# IIS Express Port Numbering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

Web Application projects and WCF projects have a project URL setting in Visual Studio as shown below:

[image]

This makes sense to me as I realise these projects run on IIS Express.  The port seems to be different for each project.  Why is this? The reason I ask is because the port is always consistent in IIS (unless you add another binding).

If I install Visual Studio on another PC, then will the ports change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS Express Project Url is saved in csproj project file.  So when you run the project on another PC, the port will stay the same.

```
<Project>
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties>
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:50380/</IISUrl>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```